# JAXB Error with Map

Tags: web-services, dictionary, jaxb

I have a logic that requires mashalling/unmashalling of . I am using the metro implementation of jaxws.
I used the recommendation from Blaise [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html) and it worked for scenarios where my Object data are Strings. For the ones having List as data I noticed, on the client side (over the network), JAXB generated it's own custom ArrayList class that extended custom AbstractList as shown below:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "arrayList")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    CustomFieldMap.class
})
public class ArrayList
    extends AbstractList
{


}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "abstractList")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ArrayList.class
})
public abstract class AbstractList
    extends AbstractCollection
{


}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "abstractCollection")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    AbstractList.class
})
public abstract class AbstractCollection {


}
```

I thought the above is a bit weird because, when the client need to consume the ArrayList data, no value is presented, given that it is using the custom ArrayList instead of java.util.ArrayList

My models looks like so:

```
@XmlSeeAlso( { CFMap.class, CField.class, ArrayList.class } )
public final class MAdapt
      extends
         XmlAdapter< CFMap, Map< String, Object >>
{
   @Override
   public CFMap marshal( Map< String, Object > pCField )
         throws Exception
   {
      CFMap vCFMap = new CFMap();

      // ignore custom fields having null values
      if( pCField == null )
      {
         return vCFMap;
      }

      for( Entry< String, Object > vEntry : pCField.entrySet() )
      {
         CField vCField = new CField();
         vCField.key = vEntry.getKey();
         vCField.value = vEntry.getValue();
         vCFMap.add( vCField );
      }

      return vCFMap;
   }

   @Override
   public Map< String, Object > unmarshal( CFMap pCFMap )
         throws Exception
   {
      HashMap< String, Object > vHashMap = new HashMap< String, Object >();

      if( pCFMap == null )
      {
         return vHashMap;
      }

      pCFMap.forEach( p -> vHashMap.put( p.key, p.value ) );

      return vHashMap;
   }
}



@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
@XmlSeeAlso({CField.class, ArrayList.class})
public class CFMap extends ArrayList< CField >
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @XmlElement (name = "cField")
   public List< CField > getCFields()
   {
      return this;
   }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso( { MAdapt.class, CFMap.class, ArrayList.class } )
public class CField
{
   @XmlElement( nillable = true )
   public String key;

   @XmlElement( nillable = true )
   public Object value;
}
```

The usage is:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TestC
{
    ....
    protected Map< String, Object > csFields;

    @XmlElement( name = "cfields" )
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter( MAdapt.class )
    public Map< String, Object > getCsFields()
    {
      return customFields;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to eventually solve the mystery.

I modified the Adapter by creating a sub class to handle Collection Type like so:

```
@XmlType (name = "itemList")
public static class CType 
{
    @XmlElement (name = "item")
    private Collection<?> items;
}
```

and then performed necessary sanity check during data marshaling:

```
@Override
public CFMap marshal( Map< String, Object > pCField )
     throws Exception
{
  .....

  for( Entry< String, Object > vEntry : pCField.entrySet() )
  {
     ...
     Object vTempV = vEntry.getValue();
     if (vTempV instanceof Collection< ? >)
     {
        CType wrapper = new CType();
        wrapper.collection = (Collection< ? >) vTempV;
        vCustomField.value = wrapper;
     }
     else
     {
        vCustomField.value = vTempV;
     }

     vCFMap.add( vCField );
  }

  return vCFMap;
}
```